# Understanding spark physical plan

Tags: sql, apache-spark, query-optimization, apache-spark-sql, catalyst

I'm trying to understand physical plans on spark but I'm not understanding some parts because they seem different from traditional rdbms. For example, in this plan below, it's a plan about a query over a hive table. The query is this:

```
select
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus,
        sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
        sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) * (1 + l_tax)) as sum_charge,
        avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,
        avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
        avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
        count(*) as count_order
    from
        lineitem
    where
        l_shipdate <= '1998-09-16'
    group by
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus
    order by
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus;


== Physical Plan ==
Sort [l_returnflag#35 ASC,l_linestatus#36 ASC], true, 0
+- ConvertToUnsafe
   +- Exchange rangepartitioning(l_returnflag#35 ASC,l_linestatus#36 ASC,200), None
      +- ConvertToSafe
         +- TungstenAggregate(key=[l_returnflag#35,l_linestatus#36], functions=[(sum(l_quantity#31),mode=Final,isDistinct=false),(sum(l_extendedpr#32),mode=Final,isDistinct=false),(sum((l_extendedprice#32 * (1.0 - l_discount#33))),mode=Final,isDistinct=false),(sum(((l_extendedprice#32 * (1.0l_discount#33)) * (1.0 + l_tax#34))),mode=Final,isDistinct=false),(avg(l_quantity#31),mode=Final,isDistinct=false),(avg(l_extendedprice#32),mode=Fl,isDistinct=false),(avg(l_discount#33),mode=Final,isDistinct=false),(count(1),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[l_returnflag#35,l_linestatus,sum_qty#0,sum_base_price#1,sum_disc_price#2,sum_charge#3,avg_qty#4,avg_price#5,avg_disc#6,count_order#7L])
            +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(l_returnflag#35,l_linestatus#36,200), None
               +- TungstenAggregate(key=[l_returnflag#35,l_linestatus#36], functions=[(sum(l_quantity#31),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(sum(l_exdedprice#32),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(sum((l_extendedprice#32 * (1.0 - l_discount#33))),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(sum(((l_extendedpri32 * (1.0 - l_discount#33)) * (1.0 + l_tax#34))),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(avg(l_quantity#31),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(avg(l_extendedce#32),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(avg(l_discount#33),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false),(count(1),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[l_retulag#35,l_linestatus#36,sum#64,sum#65,sum#66,sum#67,sum#68,count#69L,sum#70,count#71L,sum#72,count#73L,count#74L])
                  +- Project [l_discount#33,l_linestatus#36,l_tax#34,l_quantity#31,l_extendedprice#32,l_returnflag#35]
                     +- Filter (l_shipdate#37 <= 1998-09-16)
                        +- HiveTableScan [l_discount#33,l_linestatus#36,l_tax#34,l_quantity#31,l_extendedprice#32,l_shipdate#37,l_returnflag#35], astoreRelation default, lineitem, None
```

For what I'm understanding in the plan is:

1. First starts with a Hive table scan
2. Then it filter using where the condition
3. Then project to get the columns we want
4. Then TungstenAggregate?
5. Then TungstenExchange?
6. Then TungstenAggregate again?
7. Then ConvertToSafe?
8. Then sorts the final result

But I'm not understanding the 4, 5, 6 and 7 steps. Do you know what they are? I'm looking for information about this so I can understand the plan but I'm not finding anything concrete.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Lets look at the structure of the SQL query you use:

```sql
SELECT
    ...  -- not aggregated columns  #1
    ...  -- aggregated columns      #2
FROM
    ...                          -- #3
WHERE
    ...                          -- #4
GROUP BY
    ...                          -- #5
ORDER BY
    ...                          -- #6
```

As you already suspect:

- `Filter (...)` corresponds to predicates in `WHERE` clause (`#4`)
- `Project ...` limits number of columns to those required by an union of (`#1` and `#2`, and `#4` / `#6` if not present in `SELECT`)
- `HiveTableScan` corresponds to `FROM` clause (`#3`)

Remaining parts can attributed as follows:

- `#2` from `SELECT` clause - `functions` field in `TungstenAggregates`
- `GROUP BY` clause (`#5`):

  - `TungstenExchange` / hash partitioning
  - `key` field in `TungstenAggregates`
- `#6` - `ORDER BY` clause.

Project Tungsten in general describes a set of optimizations used by Spark `DataFrames` (-`sets`) including:

- explicit memory management with `sun.misc.Unsafe`. It means "native" (off-heap) memory usage and explicit memory allocation / freeing outside GC management. These conversions correspond to `ConvertToUnsafe` / `ConvertToSafe` steps in the execution plan. You can learn some interesting details about unsafe from  [Understanding sun.misc.Unsafe](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe)
- code generation - different meta-programming tricks designed to generate code that better optimized during compilation. You can think of it as an internal Spark compiler which does things like rewriting nice functional code into ugly for loops.

You can learn more about Tungsten in general from [Project Tungsten: Bringing Apache Spark Closer to Bare Metal](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html). [Apache Spark 2.0: Faster, Easier, and Smarter](https://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/12891/202021) provides some examples of code generation.

`TungstenAggregate` occurs twice because data is first aggregated locally on each partition, than shuffled, and finally merged. If you are familiar with RDD API this process is roughly equivalent to `reduceByKey`.

If execution plan is not clear you can also try to convert resulting `DataFrame` to `RDD` and analyze output of `toDebugString`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just didnt understand clearly this part "#2 from SELECT clause - functions field in TungstenAggregates". If you can explain better woud be nice!

Comment: `Functions` field lists all the aggregations which are performed in a given stage, while `Key` field describes grouping. it is `df.groupBy(*key).agg(*functions)`.

Comment: @zero323 `GROUP BY clause (#4):` should be `GROUP BY clause (#5):`. I would like to edit by myself, but stackOverflow show me that `Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?`

Answer (score 3):

Tungsten is the new memory engine in Spark since 1.4, which manages data outside JVM to save some GC overhead. You can imagine doing that involves copy data from and to JVM. That's it. In Spark 1.5 you can turn Tungsten off through `spark.sql.tungsten.enabled` then you will see the "old" plan, in Spark 1.6 I think you can't turn it off any more.