# What is the difference between hashAggregate and tungstenAggregate?

Tags: apache-spark, hash, tungus

I have noticed that, in the spark sql query physical plan, there are two types of aggregations. I wanna know the difference between "hashAggregation" and "tungstenAggregation". I have shown, two types of physical plan for reference. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add the plan. On GitHub you can some information in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/aggregate)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505638/understanding-spark-physical-plan